# How can we pass value in expression of a json path extractor from csv in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Following the JSON expression:

```
$..JobStages..JobStageActivities..ActivityID
```

How can we pass ActivityID value from CSV file or from variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter variable (also created from CSV) inside expression using `${}` format:

```
$..JobStages..JobStageActivities..${ActivityID}
```

Comment: Following is the json response that i am getting for one request.

"JobStages": [{
  "JobStageName": "Screening Phase",
  "JobStageID": 1,
  "Message": "",
  "JobStageIsRequired": true,
  "JobStageIsAnyRequired": false,
  "JobStageActivities": [{
   "ActivityName": "Phone Call",
   "ActivityIsRequired": false,
   "ActivityID": 1,
   "IsActivityRejected": false
  }]
How can I extract value of ActivityIsRequired for Activity Phone Call using json extractor in Jmeter? for example i want to extract value of ActivityIsRequired for ActivityName.